# How to pass list of values for a particular field in Elastic Search Query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-ruby

I have a query to search for a `provider_id` from the `Elastic Search Cluster`. I am using the below query to get results for a single  `provider_id` but need help in figuring out how can I pass a list of providers.

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [{
            "match": {
                "message.provider_id": {
                    "query": 943523,
                    "type": "phrase"
                }
            }
        }]
    }
}
}
```

Suppose I want to search for `provider_ids = [913523, 923523, 923523, 933523, 953523]` then how should I modify the query?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could index the provider_id as not_analyzed and then use a terms query:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "terms": {
           "message.provider_id": [
              "913523", "923523", "923523", "933523", "953523"
           ]
        }
    }
}
```

or as a bool query with a filter if you are not going to need the score:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "filter": [
            {
               "terms": {
                  "message.provider_id": [
                      "913523", "923523", "923523", "933523", "953523"
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```